# Issues with Hadoop on Ubuntu22.04.2 LTS

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to run Hadoop on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. I downloaded and followed all the steps outlined in the tutorials online. However, I am getting this error:

```
2023-06-26 22:43:51,513 INFO namenode.NameNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2023-06-26 22:43:51,598 INFO namenode.NameNode: createNameNode [-format]
2023-06-26 22:43:51,717 ERROR conf.Configuration: error parsing conf yarn-site.xml
com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element <configuration>
 at [row,col,system-id]: [30,0,"file:/home/rat42/hadoop-3.2.4/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml"]
```

Maybe the same error propagates and does not let me use the localhost on the browser to see the GUI Hadoop.

Comment: Exactly what tutorial are you referring to? The error says your yarn-site.xml is incorrectly defined, `expecting a close tag for element <configuration>`  so use a different tutorial or [edit] your question to include the file. I'd also recommend using latest 3.3 hadoop version